# In Android Room is there any way to fire change event only once for multiple insertion/update queries?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I have a live data (the list of items wrapped with RxJava2 Observable) fetched from Android Room. Now I need to run multiple queries that update this table. Every update of the table fires change-event. What I want to achieve is to fire change-event only once at the end. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such case [Transaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction) annotation will work for you (look at `insertAndDeleteInTransaction` method).

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping all your updates in a single transaction should take care of it.